# how to use a regular expression to get a string from quotes

Tags: c#

let's say there is a line "link =" - direct "C:/directory/" " I'm trying to use a regular expression to get "C:/directory" - only without quotes - C:/directory

```
Regex p = new Regex(""([^"]+)""); 

string dirs = p.Match(link).Value;
```

but the dirs string returns a string in quotes `"C:/directory"` , where it is necessary to correct the regular expression so that the string is without quotes

Comment: If you gonna add command line parameters to your app, then give a try to third-party libs like `Cocona` (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=cocona). It will help you to save nerves and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var link = "- direct \"C:/directory/\"";
var p = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"-\s*direct\s*\""([^\""]+)\""");

var result = p.Match(link).Groups[1].Value;

System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

No quotes detected :) You have used "()" so result is shown as an array of groups where first element is a full match, second is a match in ().